# ffmpeg avformat_open_input cannot open file

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to open an existing Mp3 file via Android NDK, but it won't open.

Java

```
private static String FILENAME = "/mnt/sdcard/My Audios/Doomsday.mp3";
```

C

```
if ((res=avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, path, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "file name: %s", path);
    printf("Hello %s\n", path);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "cannot open input file");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "%d", res);
    return res; // couldn't open file
}
```

Here's the log

[image: error]

Definitely sure the file exists.
Thanks.

Comment: zyoo, did u get any solution for it?. if so, can you share with us. it would be really helpful for us.

Comment: i forgot about the solution, i think i kept searching for various ffmpeg builds and finally got it working, sorry i couldn't help..

Answer (score 3):

The error code -1330794744 means "Protocol not found".
Perhaps you forgot to call the `av_register_all()` function.

Comment: I called that function, but I checked again, I've compiled ffmpeg without flag --enable-protocols, is that the cause? I'm trying to build ffmpeg again

Comment: Did you find any solution, Me too interested and willing to know what this error is and how to avoid it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone who's coming into this late (like me):
I was getting an error called Invalid argument, I don't know if it's the same, but I fixed it by making sure I had declared pFormatCtx * = avformat_alloc_context();.